# Swift and Parse updated, can't set cache policy of query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Before updating to Swift 1.2 and Parse 1.7.1, I was able to set the cache policies on my queries, no problem. However, after updating, when I try, say:

```
var query = PFQuery()
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
```

I get a compiler error that the `kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork` is an unresolved identifier. Does anyone know why this is the case? And if so, what can I do to fix it? I didn't delete any libraries when I updated the parse framework, and I made sure that all the necessary libraries are still linked in build phases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct answer is that it has to be changed to

```
var query = PFQuery()
query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
```

Hope this helps anyone that comes looking later!

Comment: I was having issues with error codes and this helped point me in the right direction. PFErrorCode.ErrorObjectNotFound was what I needed and this answer helped me find the PFErrorCode now had all these constants. Thanks!